# Can i change a variable after I define it in WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have defined a variable in my WIX as follows which has a default value as -

```
 <?define INSTALLEDVERSION = "Prod" ?>
```

Now I want to update this variable to Test based on a condition inside of my WIX. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, WiX [Preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) variables are built-time entities so you have to use a build-time condition.

```
<?define INSTALLEDVERSION = "Prod" ?> 
<?if $(var.IsTestBuild) ?>
    <?undef INSTALLEDVERSION ?> 
    <?define INSTALLEDVERSION = "Test" ?> 
<?endif ?>
```

---

If you meant an install-time condition, use a [Property](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html) element and update it with a [SetProperty](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setproperty.html) element.